# How to group by where at least two rows have differing column values

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by

I have a table that I would like to query to return results where the bit column IsValid has opposite values for at least two rows.

```
TableA
    UniqueId
    Column1
    Column2
    Column3
    IsValid (bit values 0 and 1)
```

Grouping by Columns 1,2,3 I need to return the entire rows where there are at least two rows having IsValid 0 and 1.

```
Val1 | Val1 | Val1 | 0
Val1 | Val1 | Val1 | 1

Val2 | Val2 | Val2 | 0
Val2 | Val2 | Val2 | 1
Val2 | Val2 | Val2 | 1

Val3 | Val3 | Val3 | 0
Val3 | Val3 | Val3 | 0
```

All rows Val1 and Val2 would be returned and Val3 rows would not.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `group by` with `having`.

```
select column1,column2,column3
from tableA
group by column1,column2,column3
having count(case when isvalid=1 then 1 end) >= 1
and count(case when isvalid=0 then 1 end) >= 1
```

or

```
select column1,column2,column3
from tableA
group by column1,column2,column3
having min(cast(isvalid as int)) = 0 and max(cast(isvalid as int))= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all *rows* (unaggregated), then you can do this with `exists`:

```
select a.*
from tableA a
where exists (select 1
              from tableA a2
              where a2.column1 = a.column1 and
                    a2.column2 = a.column2 and
                    a2.column3 = a.column3 and
                    isvalid = 0
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from tableA a2
              where a2.column1 = a.column1 and
                    a2.column2 = a.column2 and
                    a2.column3 = a.column3 and
                    isvalid = 1
             );
```

If you want the aggregated values, then @vkp's approach is correct.